# What is the AttributeError in this code? Pathon 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    # Do the fun!
def fire(self):

    self.printHeader()
    print ("Hitting webserver in mode '{0}' with {1} workers running {2} connections each. Hit CTRL+C to cancel.").format(self.method, self.nr_workers, self.nr_sockets)

    if DEBUG:
        print ("Starting {0} concurrent workers").format(self.nr_workers)
```

AttributEerror: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are formatting after print statement is closed

```
print (x).format(something)
#       ^ Move this parentheses to end
```

What you need is this:

```
print ("Starting {0} concurrent workers".format(self.nr_workers))
#                                                               ^ here
```

---

In Python 2 however, it wouldn't have mattered:

```
>>> print ("Starting {0} concurrent workers").format(5)
Starting 5 concurrent workers
```

Comment: the problem in line 165, see the picture

Comment: I did see the picture and added the answer. Try the code in the answer. If you don't understand it let me know. On a separate note, you should not add pictures but copy paste the stacktrace in your question itself.

Comment: Glad to be of help and Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please do read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thank you for this, do you any idea about  this error "indexError tuple index out of range", after I solved the AttributEerror it gives me this error in the same line

Comment: I cannot comment on that unless it is clear what is `self` and how it is bein instantiated. But just looking at the error it seems that you are trying to access an index from a tuple while the tuple has lesser items. e.g. let's say your tuple has 4 items and you are trying to access 5th one you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Python 3, the parentheses are part of the `print()` function call. If you were on Python 2, they would simply be grouping the string (unnecessarily, I might add). I'll illustrate with extra parentheses:

What is happening at first glance, and would in Python 2:

```
print   ( ("Starting {0} concurrent workers").format(self.nr_workers) )
```

What is actually happening, as you are using Python 3:

```
(print("Starting {0} concurrent workers")).format(self.nr_workers)
```

Since `print()` calls return `None`, it is trying to use `format()` on `None` and failing.

To format the actual string (using stylistically-proper parentheses), put the format inside the print call.

```
print("Starting {0} concurrent workers".format(self.nr_workers))
```

Comment: the problem in line 165, see the picture

Comment: @Remona - It'd be the _exact same error for the exact same reason_. AKS and I just used the other line because it was shorter.

Comment: ok it solved but it gave me another error indexError tuple index out of range